# Expand Usercontrol to full window size 

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, maximize

I am currently working on a project which has a tab control which contains a Wrap panel which contain a series of user controls. I am looking for a way to allow the user to select one user control and maximize it to the size of the tab control/window.

One thought is to simply remove all the other items from the panel.However I am attempting to use MVVM as much as possible and I'm not sure how much the user control should know about the panel. (The user control will contain a button to allow maximizing)

Is there a way to temporarily remove the usercontrol from the grid and treat it like a modal popup or just to fill the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about having "**Visible**" or "**Maximized**" bool properties in the view model *for each user control based item*, and databind said user controls **Visibility** property to the appropriate property.  Then bind your user controls maximize/restore button to command in the view model to change the VM properties appropriately?