# How to popup a usercontrol to fullscreen from a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, popup, fullscreen

Is there a way to pop a usercontrol/control let say a Grid,ViewBox or custom control from a WPF application to fullscreen or to a modal window? And put it back to it's orginal place when you press esc.

A Scenario could be that you have a WPF application consisting of a grid with two columns. Where the first shows a image preview and the second one shows list of images. When you double click the image preview it pops to fullscreen or as a modal dialog.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Image Content="Left" Grid.Column="0" />

  <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="1" Width="5">

  <ListBox Content="Right" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

I have scouted the www for a answer without any success.
Any Ideas or examples or links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A Popup that covers more than 75 percent of the screen, reduces its width first
     and then its height to meet the maximum coverage limit of 75 percent.
```

You cannot cover full screen as explained by MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode%28VS.85%29.aspx). Maximum a pop up dialog can cover 75% of the full screen

Comment: Thanks, for fast reply. I have checked out the Popup control, i am trying to do this on a multimonitor system I have some difficulties of showing the popup on one screen and WPF on another. Also I need to cover 100% of the screen. I tried then to create a modal dialog and move it to the second screen without any success.

Comment: Thanks , i thought i was losing it :) . 
It just always was 3/4 of the screen no mater what i did.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a somewhat similar question last week. Which can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079445/expand-usercontrol-to-full-window-size).

I ended up using a wrap panel which has its height and width set to auto and contains a list of controls. (I use custom logic to calculate the height/width of each control).

When a user selects a control, I set the visibility to false on all the other controls. Which makes it appear that the selected control is now full screen.

When the user cancels the selection, loop through all the controls and set them to be visible again.

If a grid is needed and you do not want to use custom logic. You could always put an image on top of the other controls on the form and have its default visibility to false. you could bind the image source property to the selected item property. Then the image can be displayed when the selection is not null?

Comment: That's a definitive a solution i have already checked out your post there. What I am acctualy looking for is a multi monitor support where i want to see a fullscreen user control and still be able to see the second column inside the WPF application. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I've had a quick look around and it looks as though it isn't easy to open another window on a second monitor. I have found one example of how it could work [here](http://mostlytech.blogspot.com/2008/01/maximizing-wpf-window-to-second-monitor.html)

Comment: I was thinkig of creating a Modal Dialog and adding the usercontrol to it without losing ViewModel connection, and then expanding the window to fullscreen. Have not figured out how to do it yet.